# Access elements of embedded document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to be able to access classes from an embedded vimeo video. My iframe looks like this:

HTML

```
<iframe id="vimeo" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/85509673?portrait=0&amp;badge=0&amp;color=a82a2a" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I am trying to add a click event to the `play-button-cell` class like so:

jQuery

```
var embeddedContent = $("#vimeo");
console.log(embeddedContent);
var doc = embeddedContent.contentDocument; // get the inner DOM
console.log(doc); 
console.log(doc.jQuery(".play-button-cell"));

doc.jQuery(".play-button-cell").click(function(){
    alert('ok!');
});
```

and I get the following error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'jQuery' of undefined
```

`play-button-cell` does exist because I can see it when I "inspect element" on the play button.
How can I access a class in the embedded content? Is this possible?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YAPD3/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not do-able, unless:

1. Your page is hosted on vimeo.com, or
2. vimeo.com allows your domain to execute cross-domain interaction.

This is done for security reasons - Think... visiting a page that a person hosted. And the person placed in IFRAME on their blog, use JavaScript to post a Facebook status on your behave - That's bad, isn't it?

This security measure is called Same Origin Policy (For security reasons.) You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

P.S. If you debug the code, you should see $('#vimeo').contentDocument returns NULL (Or throws an exception depends on the browser you use.)